# Find all continuity points

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let:

$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2 $ if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$ and

$f(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$ otherwise

find all contiunity points (x,y,z)

My solution:

Let split $\mathbb{R^3}$ at $D_1 , D_2$ such that $D_1=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}: x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}  \}$ and $D_2= \mathbb{R^3} - D_1 $

then I'm not sure if it's true that if

$\displaystyle \lim _{(x,y,z) \to(a,b,c)} f(x,y,z)=G_1$ for $x,y,z \in D_1$ and

$\displaystyle \lim _{(x,y,z) \to(a,b,c)} f(x,y,z)=G_2$ for $x,y,z \in D_2$ and

$G_1=G_2$ then we have the limit exist at $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ and it's equal $G_1$

if it's true then we have $f$ is continous at points $(x,x,x)$

Comment: Why wouldn't the function be continuous at points $(x,x,x)$ in any case?

Comment: The component function definitions are continuous if extended on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, while the domains of the components are not continuous anywhere.  So a necessary and sufficient condition for continuity at a point is that the component definitions are equal at that point.

Comment: It **is** true, but there are other continuity points ((1,1,2), for example). Your question is about finding continuity points or about a proof to your statement?

Comment: @Abstraction question is about continuity points, but I think the statemement would be helpful, how did you find the continuity at (1,1,2) ?

Comment: @thomas Sorry, got that wrong. You need to solve $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=0$, but $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz=(x-y/2-z/2)^2+3/4(y-z)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous at a point if any sequence of points approaching it has the same limit. For this function that means we can take a rational or irrational sequence for either kind of limit (rational or irrational). Either way, for continuity we must have the equality

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x y + y z + x z$$

This is clearly satisfied at all points $(x,x,x)$ but are there others? Well we can [solve for one variable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[%20x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%20z%5E2%20-%20x%20y%20-%20x%20z%20-%20y%20z%20%3D%3D%200%2C%20z]) in terms of the others. You can see that, say, $z$ is real at a point of continuity only when $x = y$. And at those points, we also have $z = x = y$. So these are the ONLY continuity points.